# How to add some filter to Category Taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy

How to add some extra filter to Category Taxonomy list to backend, just after Bulk Action Drop-down want to add another filter Drop-down. For example, search only parent category or search with some custom meta added to category etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Exclude child categories when getting posts from parent:

use [`category__in`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Here using category id:

`$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__in' => 4 ) );`

### Excluding children of custom taxonomies:

[`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) argument of `WP_Query` has `include_children` set to true by default, so you can set that to false.

> include_children (boolean) - Whether or not to include children for
>   hierarchical taxonomies. Defaults to true.

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'include_children' => false,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

### Excluding Children and only getting posts in category 4 with people taxonomy:

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => 4,
            'include_children' => false,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

NOTE: see the Tax_query link above for more nested/complicated queries.

Comment: Hi @hwl thanks for the reply. But I am looking for backend Category list filter. I have edited my question, hope you can get it.